# Making cell entry the name of a column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, excel, numpy, pandas, scipy

Lets say that I have a dataframe (using pandas data analysis library) that looks like so:

```
   Unnamed Column1:
1  'Puppies'
2  6
3  15
4  13
5  12
```

And I want to get the dataframe to look like this:

```
   'Puppies'
1  6
2  15
3  13
4  12
5  80
```

How does one shift everything up, including entries to replace the column name. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]   # set the columns to the values in the first row
df = df.iloc[1:]          # reassign df to all rows but the first
```

---

Note that `"Unnamed: 1"` sounds suspiciously like the name `pd.read_csv` assigns to the column if the header row lacked a column name. In that case, instead of patching up the result as shown above, you might be able to fix the problem with [`skiprows=1`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) or `header=1` instead. `skiprows=1` would cause `pd.read_csv` to skip the first row and thus read the headers (column names) from the second row automatically.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!